# How to remove distance between blocks

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have these blocks. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKqBt.jpg)

How can I make left block higher than right block and remove distance between them?
This is css:

```
.cnt {
  padding:20px;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  overflow:hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 90px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
  .cnt {
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
  .cnt {
    height: 452px;
    padding: 30px;
  }
}    
@media all and (max-width: 1170px) {
    .cnt {
        height: 380px;
    }
}
```

This is html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-6  col-xs-12">
  <div class="cnt"></div>
</div>                                   
<div class="col-md-6  col-xs-12">
  <div class="cnt"></div>
</div>
```

These block are responsive, and under each other in mobile version. The problem is that I can not remove distance between them. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override default Bootstrap css like this, the classes col-md-6 and col-xs-12 by default will have padding and margin which is causing the distance you are talking about. And also remove margin from .cnt class:-

```
.col-md-6, .col-xs-12{
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: This is not a good idea because you will add padding 0 and margin 0 to all elements with classes col-md-6 and col-xs-12 in whole  page.

Comment: then do it inline for these to boxes only. or define a class with margin and padding 0 and place it in these divs.

Comment: easiest and simpler way is to add bootstrap classes to html, m-0 and p-0 but if you want better solution look at my answer

Comment: Yep. you are right. If the person is using bootstrap 4 that would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:10px;` from .cnt class ! It is main problem

Answer (score 0):

You should use bootstrap classes for remove padding and margin between blocks:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/

I added to yours code classes **pr-md-0 and pl-md-0 mr-md-0 and ml-md-0** what means:

**pr-md-0** (padding right for medium device equal to 0)

**pl-md-0** (padding left for medium device equal to 0)

**mr-md-0** (margin right for medium device equal to 0)

**ml-md-0** (margin left for medium device equal to 0)

This changes are for left and right space between them but if you want to get rid off space top and bottom you sould add different classes fo example:
**mt-0 mb-0 pt-0 pb-0**

what means:

**mt-0** - margin top to 0

**pt-0** - padding top to 0

**mb-0** - margin bottom to 0

**pb-0** - padding bottom to 0

For different height for each block you should give different classes instead of using same  class **cnt** for example add **cnt1** and **cnt2** class like in example below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>

    <style>
    .cnt {
  padding:20px;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  overflow:hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 90px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
  .cnt {
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
  .cnt {
    padding: 30px;
  }
  .cnt1 {
    height: 552px;
  }

  .cnt2 {
    height: 452px;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 1170px) {
  .cnt1 {
    height: 480px;
  }

  .cnt2 {
    height: 380px;
  }
 }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6  col-xs-12 mr-md-0 pr-md-0 ">
          <div class="cnt cnt1 mb-0 mt-md-4">

          </div>
        </div>                                                                 

        <div class="col-md-6  col-xs-12 ml-md-0 pl-md-0 ">
          <div class="cnt cnt2 mt-0 mt-md-4">

          </div>
        </div>  
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

For margin and padding

Comment: Switon, but now they are not under each other in mobile version

Comment: They will be if you add classes mb-0 to first block and mt-0 to second block as is described.

Comment: I modified answer, now block are under each other. But a good advice for you is use  as much as possible bootstrap classes because its very good defined instead of using own css for building layout grid.

Comment: Switon, but they still are not under each other

Answer (score 0):

Change this CSS then remove the distance between the blocks:

```
.cnt {
    padding:auto;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    overflow:hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 90px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```